# Can't pass UITableViewCell didSelectRowAtIndexPath data to another view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have currently got a UITableView in my main view controller. I want the data of the selected row to be passed to another view controller in my project.

Here's what I have got so far, although there is an error. Why is this? I have referenced the class and the header file in my .h file.
[image]

I would really appreciate some help with this as I've tried everything I can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Simply synthesize the object in the destination view.
It will work fine...

like:
in .h

 @property(nonatomic, retain) UILabel *note;

in .m 
@synthesize note;
```

Comment: But one thing, I put `[an.note setText:selectedNote];` except the text doesn't actually change in the other view. What's gone wrong?

Comment: well, but you can take NSString in other view, and then assign the string value in that view will be done easily.

Comment: I mean, don't assign string value to the label directly from the current view.

Comment: The text is just blank if I do that :(

Comment: I think u did'nt connected the object with xib.

Comment: Do one thing, remove selectedNote Variable and directly assign like below: an.note.text = [noteTitles obj......] ;// this line

Comment: If not getting, then try like: AddNote *an = [[AddNote alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddNote"] bundle:nil];// instruction  and check once whether your array having data or not?

Comment: @objc-obsessive to set textView's text property, your other viewcontroller's view must be loaded. Else the IBOutlet of textView will not be initialized (as its in nib file). To load view either you will be accessing view property of other view controller or pushing/presenting it.

Answer (score 1):

Very Simple,I think note is a  UILabel,

according to You error 
please use this code in AddNote. h file

```
     NSString  *noteStr; //Ios 4
     IBoutlet   UILabel *note;


@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString  *noteStr; //Ios 4
@property(nonatomic, retain) UILabel *note;



@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString   *noteStr;
 @property(nonatomic, strong) UILabel *note;   //Ios 5
```

In AddNote. .m file

```
@synthesize note,noteStr;

self.note.text=noteStr; //in ViewWillAppear
```

Some Time Application is crash Because Memory IF you Work In Ios 4  Please Correct this code

```
an.noteStr - [selectNote retain];
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare static variable for global use.
Using keyword extern

```
Create Common.h

extern NSMutableArray *gMyBasketCollectionList;


common.m

NSMutableArray *gMyBasketCollectionList;


Use This Mutable Aarray to Store Your Data and Display in Any other
include common.h in First View And SecondView 
Add Object to mutable Array in First View And 
Show SecondView And Display access that Array
```